# Absolute Route URLs with Ring and Compojure

Tags: clojure, absolute-path, compojure, ring

I need to redirect users to an absolute URL following oAuth authentication.

How do I construct an absolute URL for a Compojure route? Non-AJAX HTTP requests seem to omit the `Origin` header. Is there a Ring or Compojure helper function to build absolute URLs, or should I do this manually with the scheme and `Host` headers?

Lastly, and probably deserving of a separate question, are there helper functions in Compojure to generate route URLs based on the handler, ala `Html.ActionLink(...)` in MVC land?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ring-headers](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-headers) project has a [middleware](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-headers/blob/master/src/ring/middleware/absolute_redirects.clj) that transforms relative to absolute urls:

```
(ns ring.middleware.absolute-redirects
  "Middleware for correcting relative redirects so they adhere to the HTTP RFC."
  (:require [ring.util.request :as req])
  (:import  [java.net URL MalformedURLException]))

(defn- url? [^String s]
  (try (URL. s) true
       (catch MalformedURLException _ false)))

(defn absolute-url [location request]
  (if (url? location)
    location
    (let [url (URL. (req/request-url request))]
      (str (URL. url location)))))
```